# Partially flatten multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, coordinates

I have an array of outlines and points. For an outline, calling `outline.geometry.coordinates` produces a multidimensional array of coordinates:

```
[[[-72.68639118392117,41.66733032827929],[-72.68630366033922,41.667449647115724], ...]]
```

For a point, calling `point.geometry.coordinates` produces a one dimensional array of the coordinates:

```
[-72.78630766033722,41.767349642115724]
```

Both points and outlines are held in an array.  I would like to ultimately end up with an array of all of the coordinate pairs, such as:

```
 [[[-72.68639118392117,41.66733032827929],[-72.68630366033922,41.667449647115724],[-72.78630766033722,41.767349642115724], ...]]
```

---

**What I've Tried**

First, I tried to get all of the coordinates, where `geometries` is my array of outlines and points:

```
var coordinates = geometries.map(function(outline) {return outline.geometry.coordinates});
```

Not surprisingly, this creates the following array:

```
[[[[-72.68639118392117,41.66733032827929],[-72.68630366033922,41.667449647115724], ...]], [-72.78630766033722,41.767349642115724]]
```

Flattening this array would cause loss of the coordinate pairs being paired, so I'm not entirely sure how to go about this.  Any ideas?

Comment: `arr.reduce((a,b)=>a.concat(b))` flattens 1 level, which fixes the last example

Comment: Are you able to identify outlines vs points, for example, using `instanceof`?  Does `geometries` contain only `outline`s or is it mixed?

Comment: @dandavis I'm getting `a.conct is not a function`?

Comment: @dandavis: wouldn't that result in `[[a,b], [c,d], e, f]` where `e` and `f` aren't paired?

Comment: @arcyqwerty: mmm. yeah, probably. OP should pop() out that last one then flatten, then push

Comment: @arcyqwerty No way to differentiate them -_- and `geometries` has both mixed in

Comment: Can you please show the value of `geometries`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
var geometries = [
    // point
    {
        geometry: {
            coordinates: [1, 2],
        },
    },

    // outline
    {
        geometry: {
            coordinates: [
                [
                    [3, 4],
                    [5, 6],
                ],
            ],
        },
    },
];

var coordinates = geometries.map(function(outline) {
  var coords = outline.geometry.coordinates;
  if (typeof coords[0] === 'number') {
    return [coords];
  } else {
    return coords[0];
  }
}).reduce(function (prev, next) {
    return prev.concat(next);
}, []);

console.log(coordinates);

// Output:
// [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ] ]
```

Comment: That seems to result in an array of the format: 
`[[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6] ... ], [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6] ... ], [1, 2]]`

Comment: Well, my code including input and output is above. Perhaps your input looks different from mine?

Comment: Ah yepp, that's it.  The only difference between our inputs is for outlines mine has `coordinates: [[
                [3, 4],
                [5, 6],
            ]]`

Comment: Ah. I'd suggest `else { return coords[0]; }` then. Unless, of course, you *want* output like `[ [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ] ] ]`.

Comment: (Edited with that suggestion.)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to standardize the coordinate outputs.  If `outline`s give you an array of paired coordinates, you can have `point`s do the same by wrapping it as a single element array.

**Outline**

```
[[a, b], [c, d], [e, f], ...]
```

**Point**

```
[[a, b]]
```

such that when you combine them they are all of the same shape / dimensionality.  At that point, you can flatten once using @dandavis' technique.

---

If you're able to use `instanceof` to determine whether your Object is an outline or point, you could use the following.

```
var coordinates = geometries.map(function(outline_or_point) {
  return outline_or_point instanceof outline ? outline.geometry.coordinates : [point.geometry.coordinates];
});
```

If `instanceof` isn't possible, you could do some duck typing, for example, by checking if `outline_or_point` is an array or a number.

```
var coordinates = geometries.map(function(outline_or_point) {
  return typeof outline_or_point[0] == 'number' ? [point.geometry.coordinates] : outline.geometry.coordinates;
});
```